# configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'general_info'

Tags: python

I have created an exe file from .py file and within that code, i retrieve a value from config.ini file. When i convert the .py to .exe file and double click on it, it works fine. But when create a task scheduler to run that exe file on windows start up, i receive an error:

```
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'general_info'
```

Noting that the section already exists and as mentioned above when run the exe file by double click on it, it works fine

code:

```
import time
import os
import subprocess
from configparser import ConfigParser, RawConfigParser
 
thisfolder = os.getcwd()  
initfile = os.path.join(thisfolder, 'config.ini').replace('\\', '\\\\')
 
config = RawConfigParser()
 
config.read(initfile)
check_every_minutes = int(config.get('general_info', 'check_every_minutes').strip()) * 60
```

config.ini:

```ini
[general_info]
check_every_minutes = 1
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I've never used Windows Task Scheduler, but I bet the CWD is not what you expected, so it's reading the wrong `config.ini`.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. It might help to add the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). See [mre]. A real MRE would include how you're converting it to EXE and how you're setting up the Task, but I bet they're irrelevant for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue solved by placing the config.ini file in C:/Windows , as the task scheduler somehow is reading from relative path which in C:/Windows

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).